# getting data from array is invalid

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

In on of my views i have the following form:

```
<table align="center" border="1">
<tr>
   <td>Identificação</td>
   <td>Conc, %</td>
   <td>Classificação 67/548/CEE</td>
   <td>Classificação 1272/2008 (CLP)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
       <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="componentes[0][identificacao]"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
       <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="componentes[0][conc]"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
       <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="componentes[0][classificacao_cee]"></textarea>
   </td>
   <td>
       <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="componentes[0][classificacao_clp]"></textarea>
   </td>
</tr>
</table>

<div id="outro_curso"></div>
<p class="submit">
    <button id="novo_curso">Add Curso</button>
</p>
```

As you can see, I'm using multidimensional arrays. I'm doing that, because when I click the "Add Curso" button  I call a jquery function that generates another table like the previous one. The names of the text areas will be `componentes[1][identificacao]`, `componentes[1][conc]`, etc...

NOTE: I can use the button to generate tables the number of times I want.

Now, my problem is how to get this data treated in my CodeIgniter model. I tried saving the data to the `$componentes` array (to later insert into the database) But I guess there is something wrong with my code:

```
$componentes;
    foreach ($this->input->post('componentes') as $key => $value){
        $componentes[$key]['identificacao']=$value[$key]['identificacao'];
        $componentes[$key]['conc']=$value[$key]['conc'];
        $componentes[$key]['classificacao_cee']=$value[$key]['classificacao_cee'];
        $componentes[$key]['classificacao_clp']=$value[$key]['classificacao_clp'];
    }
```

Can someone give me a little help please?

**EDIT:**

I forgot to mention, I'm getting the error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

So I don't know if my `foreach ($this->input->post('componentes') as $key => $value){` is correct or if is some problem in the lines inside.

Comment: From a quick look, I'm guessing you'd need this: `$componentes[$key]['identificacao'] = $value['identificacao'];`

Comment: I edited my post Mudshark. Right now i can't test your advice because i'm getting an error on my foreach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$componentes_post = $this->input->post('componentes');
if(is_array($componentes_post)&&!empty($componentes_post))
{
    foreach ($componentes_post as $key => $value)
    {
        $temp_componentes['identificacao']=$value['identificacao'];
        $temp_componentes['conc']=$value['conc'];
        $temp_componentes['classificacao_cee']=$value['classificacao_cee'];
        $temp_componentes['classificacao_clp']=$value['classificacao_clp'];
        $componentes[] = $temp_componentes;
    }
}
```

Now see,

```
print_r($componentes);
```

You should get what you need.
Next, you are getting error **Invalid argument supplied for foreach()** since the array you have iterated on `foreach` is empty, make sure value is coming on that element by using `print_r($this->input->post('componentes'))`

Comment: Couldn't ask for better. Thanks a lot hsuk, everything is working perfectly now.